# Is Sound Blaster16 a default sound card on most Laptops

Tags: assembly, nasm

Is a sound blaster16 a default soundcard on all Laptops  because ive been trying to play sounds using programing Guide ive found on Os dev website about programming sound16 blaster. Which i m failing to do

I m using a Lenovo T440P ThinkPad

Comment: No it isn't. It's likely some intel hda ac97 thingy. Consult PCI enumeration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it isn't. I think the most (not all) laptops today has realtek or intel chip as integrated sound card. Sound blaster from creative labs was big in the late 90's but not any more I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Most x86 PC *emulators* like DOSBox and BOCHS emulate a machine with a *virtual* SoundBlaster (if you enable sound), because it was common for DOS programs (like games) to have drivers for that hardware.  (In DOS days, every program needed its own drivers; there wasn't an OS interface).

But you won't find that in real modern PCs.

---

Modern x86 PCs *do* emulate some fake legacy hardware on bootup (like a PS/2 keyboard controller, and [PIT timer](https://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer)).  I think the mechanism is that in/out instructions to those ports trap to firmware (in System Management Mode) which does the emulation.

But since sound isn't essential for bootloaders to boot a real OS that can load drivers, real motherboard firmwares don't emulate an SB16 that way.  And the PC-speaker PWM beep hardware is supported or emulated.

**In modern PCs, the onboard sound hardware usually follows the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio standard**.  I'm not sure how much you can do with HW-agnostic drivers that just use that interface, and how much depends on drivers for the specific DSP on your motherboard.  (often RealTek, Analog Devices, SigmaTel, etc.)

See also

- https://wiki.osdev.org/Intel_High_Definition_Audio
- https://wiki.osdev.org/Category:Sound